# Copying the values of each <div> in an identical structure

Tags: javascript, html, jquery

I have two nested `<div>` with an identical structure. Something like this:

```html
<div class="foo" id="{{ randomNumber1 }}">Hello</div>
<div class="this" id="{{ randomNumber2 }}">
  <div class="that" id="{{ randomNumber3 }}">World</div>
  <div class="bar" id="{{ randomNumber4 }}">
    <div class="fizz" id="{{ randomNumber5 }}">
      <div class="buzz" id="{{ randomNumber6 }}">How was your day?</div>
    </div>
  </div>
  <!-- goes on -->
```

Then somewhere else, I have the same structure. However the ID of the divs are different and they have a different javascript initialized. I need to copy the value of the structure and put it in the second, identical structure.

I have tried using jQuery's html:

```
$(mySecondStructure).html($(myFirstStructure).html());
```

However this obviously breaks the IDs and therefore the javascript. Therefore the only solution is to only copy the values of each  and put it in the equivalent `<div>` in the second structure.

Is there a way to clone this easily? I know I could do an `each();` function but maybe there is already something built in

Comment: '*However this obviously breaks the IDs and therefore the javascript*' if the `id` is different, this should not 'break' anything. Note that all the `id` in your example are a problem because they are all the same, though. If by 'breaks the JS' you mean that the event handlers are lost, it's because you're creating new elements, not moving the existing. To do the latter, `append()` the first to the second instead of copying the HTML

Comment: @RoryMcCrossan I called them randomNumbers as a placeholder as I though it would be obvious that it means it's filled with random numbers. Will edit it to make more cleara, though.

Answer (score 0):

id and event binding should change after cloning part of an HTML
as follow.

```
$('yourselector')
.clone(true)
.attr('id', 'new_unique_id')
.off();
```